# bot sending an mp3 (or wav) to a user in MS teams

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building an MS Teams bot.  According to this sample, botbuilder framework supports audio, but when I actually try to do it in MS Teams it doesn't work, in that it shows the following:

[audio card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKv14.png)

Here is my code:

```
  async def send_audio(self, audio):
    logger.debug(f"Sending {audio}")
    card = AudioCard(
      title="",
      media=[MediaUrl(url=audio)],
    )
    await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.audio_card(card)))
```

inspired by:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/06.using-cards/dialogs/main_dialog.py

How can I send audio from my bot to a user?  A working sample would be best, but please don't point me to MS Documentation (It is total crap!)

Comment: Could you please share what console error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error in the console. As far as bot framework is concerned, everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following cards are implemented by the Bot Framework, but are not supported by Teams:

1. Animation cards
2. Audio cards
3. Video cards

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#cards-not-supported-in-teams

Comment: Thanks Prasad! Is there any other way to show a video, a GIF or play an audio to the user?